# Java class instance saving within body of instance

Tags: java, syntax, instance, instance-variables

Looking through oracle and java articles on this subject I couldn't find anything "wrong" or possibly "problematic" with this structure.

What I am referring to is a class that acts as a storage instance for data, and also stores itself in the same class via static getters/setters and iterators.

As below:
(Compare example 1 below to example 2 below that - which is "better/safer")?

Example 1:

```
public class Person {

    /**
     * The data stored.
     */
    private Integer age;
    private Object data;
    private String name;

    /**
     * The data handled (IN THE SAME CLASS)
     */
    private static List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addPerson(Person p){
        persons.add(p);
    }

    public static Person getPerson(int index){
        return persons.get(index);
    }
}
```

Versus:
Example 2: (split into 2 classes)

```
public class Person {

    /**
     * The data stored.
     */
    private Integer age;
    private Object data;
    private String name;
}

public class PersonDataHandler {

    /**
     * The data handled (NOT THE SAME CLASS)
     */
    private static List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addPerson(Person p){
        persons.add(p);
    }

    public static Person getPerson(int index){
        return persons.get(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better for what? Why do you need to store `Person` instances statically?

Comment: "better" in terms of safety and/or structure. Persons need to be saved statically for a huge number of reasons I cannot begin to describe

Comment: Both are bad coding style. Don’t add the instances into a `static` list at all.

Comment: @Holger How do you batch instances to process then?

Comment: I don’t know what exactly you want to do. There is nothing wrong with storing objects in an `ArrayList`. But there is never a need to reference that list from a `static` variable. Pass the list from the code creating and filling that list to the code processing the elements of that list, e.g. as a parameter or as an instance field of another object shared by them. And what do these `addPerson` and `getPerson` methods give you that’s not already provided by the `add` and `get` methods of the `List`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in creating another class for the `static` member unless you are treating `PersonDataHandler` as a `Util` class which would be used by other classes as well.

Apart from that if your static member is `public` then it doesn't matter whether it's inside `Person` class or anywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Second variant is better, at least from the view of encapsulation.
It would be better to remove "static" modifier, to make this class not global.

First variant is very strange, cause you can do that:

```
personA.addPerson(personB);
```

Which is breaking Single Responsibility Principle. (DAO and POJO at the same time)
It also leads to strange inheritance structure.